# Mystic for non-convex MINLP

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, mystic

Can mystic optimizer be used to minimize a non-convex Mixed Integer Non-Linear Programming problem with only integer inputs?Because,the objective function is not continuous in x(the input),it is discretized in integers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `mystic` author... yes.  Mystic can handle non-convex problems, with the Differential Evolution solver, or one of the Ensemble solvers.  There is no MLP-specific solver, but instead handles integer programming as a spatial map that constrains solution space -- either pass `np.round` to the solver as a constraint, or use the `integers` decorator on a constraint.

For example, see:

- https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/blob/master/examples2/integer_programming.py
- https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/blob/master/examples2/eq10.py
- https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/blob/master/examples2/eq20.py
- https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/blob/master/examples2/hotel_pricing.py

**Updated to respond to comments below**
To provide another example of constraints... if you want to impose a sum on the square of inputs, you could do it like this:

```
>>> import mystic as my
>>> squared = lambda x: [i*i for i in x]
>>> c = lambda x: my.constraints.impose_sum(24, squared(x))
>>> c([1.,2.,3.,4.])
[0.8, 3.2, 7.199999999999999, 12.8]
>>> sum(_)
24.0
```

`mystic` has several modules where you can find pre-built constraints functions, but the best places to start are: `mystic.constraints` and `mystic.tools` for general constraints, `mystic.math.measures` for statistical constraints, `mystic.symbolic` for symbolic constraints, and `mystic.penalty` for soft constraints (i.e. penalties).

Comment: Can you please tell me how we could define constraints to return some value like `return sum(func(x))==A` [where _func_ is some arbitrary function of each element in input vector], instead of writing them as equations,as shown in the examples.Because my input vector x is very large and writing it as an equation would be tedious. I searched the mystic documentation ,but didn't find it or might have missed it.